# How to decouple input params for different handlers in a filter/chain?

Tags: design-patterns, filter, refactoring, chain-of-responsibility

I have a list of filters. Every filter has different responsibility and accepts various input params. The interface looks like this:

```
void doFilter(Context context);
```

and I run it with:

```
void main(){
  context.setA(input_for_filter_a);
  context.setB(input_for_filter_b);
  context.setC(input_for_filter_c);
  //...
  firstFilter.doFilter(context);
}
```

To add a filter, I have to

1. Modify the Context, e.g. add a private field with a getter and setter.
2. Update main() to fill new input params.

Is there a way to decouple all these input params, so that different filters could focus on each params they need to know. I hope code in main() could be stable. Thanks!

P.S. Some filter may NOT have any input param.

Comment: Why are the inputs set in the main method? Is that part of the application startup? Do the inputs change during runtime?

Comment: @RicardoVeguilla They're not a part of startup but do change during runtime. In fact, those params come from a http request or session. Sounds like I'd better always put request and session into the context, but I don't have a single completed session model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a dangerous dependency between `Context` and `Filter` implementation details. With such high coupling, you suffer from problems you've already notice, e.g. you need to change `Context`, any time you add or change a `Filter`.

All `Context` should know about `Filter` is that it has a public method that executes its implementation details. And nothing more! This method is defined in the `Filter` interface.

`Filter` depends on a `Context` to exist. And it also knows how to handle its parameters.

To implement the chain of responsibility, `Context` can have a set of `Filter` objects, which it can iterate over and call the filtering method defined in the interface.

In pseudo-code it would something like this:

```
class Filter {
  function Filter(context, params) {
    // initializes a filter object with a context and its specific parameters
  }

  function run() {
    // run is the method defined by the Filter interface
    // here goes the implementation details for this filter
  }
}


class Context {
  array filters = [];

  function applyFilter(filter) {
    filters.push(filter);
  }

  function run() {
    for filter in filters {
      // all a context needs to know is how to execute a filter
      filter.run
    }
  }
}

void main() {    
  context  = new Context();
  filter_a = new Filter(context, params_a);
  filter_b = new Filter(context, params_b);

  context.applyFilter(filter_a);
  context.applyFilter(filter_b);

  context.run();
}
```

I apologize beforehand for the pseudo-code. Based on the syntax of your example, I'm guessing you're using Java or maybe C++. I don't know neither, but I tried to follow the same syntax.

I hope this shed some light on the problem. Let me know if I can make anything clearer.

Best!

Comment: I hope all of filters are injected by spring, so they can be changed in `bean.xml`. Thank you.

Comment: Note that not all of the filters need params, which types and numbers are unknow.

Comment: You could encapsulate all params in a object, e.g. FilterParams, so you can have many or even none parameters of any type you need. And this object could be instantiated by some sort of Builder or Factory. NOTE: I'm not a Java programmer nor know about Spring, but I think this might work. Let me know!

Comment: Spring is a Dependency Injection framework for java, which means method main() needn't know how many or what filters there are.

Comment: Got it! I used `main()` just to keep the same reasoning you used in your example. Besides that, using the proposed `FilterParams` object wouldn't help. Can't you create a Builder that injects FilterParams objects?

Comment: Sorry, my last comment on `FilterParams` was supposed to be a question. Creating an object to hold the params would help? Could you inject it via Spring using a Builder/Factory?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60586/discussion-between-anderson-and-wicz).

Comment: Finally I've realized that what I need is an injection with `request` scope, then each filter could get all the beans from spring.

Answer (score 0):

Is using `Map<Object, Object>` as context unacceptable? This way you can separate storage from logic. If you want algorithms to access only their respective data portions, prevent Map iteration.

If you want typesafe solution with statically ensured encapsulation, use [Role object pattern](http://st-www.cs.illinois.edu/users/hanmer/PLoP-97/Proceedings/riehle.pdf) (Facet pattern, is there better name?) to keep data for different algorithms isolated:

```java
/** Unique identifier for context data **/
public static class FacetKey<T> {
  private final Class<T> type;
  public FacetKey(Class<T> type) {
    assert type != null;
    this.type = type;
  }
}

/** Holds typed data.
  * Only key holder can access data addressed by that key.
  **/
public static class Context {
  private final Map<FacetKey, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
  public <T> T put(FacetKey<T> key, T datum) {
    return key.type.cast(data.put(key, datum));
  }
  public <T> T get(FacetKey<T> key){
    return key.type.cast(data.get(key));
  }
}

class FilterC {
  // This key is unaccessible for other clasess
  // Only FilterC can manipulate with it data
  private static final FacetKey<Boolean> key = new FacetKey<Boolean>();
  public static void enable(Context context) {
    context.put(key, true);
  } 
  public static void disable(Context context) {
    context.put(key, false);
  }       
  public static boolean doFilter(Context context) {
    return context.get(key);
  }
}

public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
  Context context = new Context();
  context.put(FilterA.key, new DataA());
  context.put(DataBFactory.key, new DataB());
  println("" + new FilterA().apply(context));
  println("" + new FilterB().apply(context));
}
```

The main idea is to share keys between datum providers and filters, but to hide them from parties which don't need access to this datum. Each key is unique and can't be recreated, so each party accessing data need to have an explicit reference to key instance, which are easily controlled by compiler and static analysis.

[Complete usage example](http://ideone.com/TftRsG)